# cref multiple labels don't grab the label type

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

I have a strange situation where `cref` is working great for single labels, i.e. `\cref{eq:some equation}` and for the first two multiple references of the form `\cref{thm:first theorem,thm:second theorem,thm:amazing third theorem}` works perfectly, and then after that multiple references get printed with the right numbers but the no type, e.g. instead of

> theorems 3.4 and 3.6

It'll print

> ?? 3.4?? 3.6

This happens both with same type labels (e.g. all theorems) and mixed type (e.g. one lemma and one theorem). I've `cref`ed each item individually and it picks up the type. I've tried doubling the comma, making sure there is no space, recompiling many many times etc. Nothing fixes this.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\newtheorem{claim}{Claim}
\begin{document}

\begin{claim} \label{b}
\end{claim}
\begin{claim} \label{c}
\end{claim}

\cref{b} % claim 1
\cref{c} % claim 2
\cref{b,c} % ?? 1?? 2

\end{document}
```

Comment: Well without an MWE, it is hard for us to reproduce your problem. A hint on producing the MWE: Make a copy of your current project. In the copy, start deleting stuff while rechecking that the problem still exists. At some point you cannot remove more. And that will be the MWE. During this process you will often pin down the actual problem your self. So the process is a vital debugging tool.

Comment: @daleif, done..

Comment: Add `\crefname{claim}{claim}{claims}` after the `\newtheorem` line.

Comment: @egreg, thanks. That fixed it and kind of makes sense (if it knows the label type it should either default to using it and pluralising with an 's', or come up with `??` for single cases, not mix the two). I think you should write that up as an answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The package `cleveref` predefines some common tags such as

> equation, figure, page, table, part, chapter, section, appendix, footnote, theorem, lemma, corollary

and some others, but it can't know in advance all the tags users want to use for their environments. The package will guess the singular form from the counter's name, but it doesn't try to build the plural form. So when the

```
\cref reference format for label type xyz
```

warning appears, it's time to help the package and define the tag. So add

```
\crefname{claim}{claim}{claims}
```

to your document preamble after the `\newtheorem` line. There's also `\Crefname` for defining the capitalized forms, but the package is normally able to guess them from the lowercase forms.

Comment: Thank you! A note for those using [theorem environment with numbers on the left](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/218302/109294), if you defined a theorem-like environment using `\newfctaylortheorem` and want to rename it, do `\crefname{fctaylor@claim}{claim}{claims}`.