# Theorem environment with numbers on the left

Tags: theorems

I am trying to construct a theorem environment which roughly looks like this:

```
1.1   Theorem   Statement of the theorem. Here is some extra text so you can see how the
      theorem body text should be indented (aligned with theorem head).
```

The theorem head should be bold, with no punctuation after. The spacing between `thmnumber` and `thmname` should be adjustable. Body text normal.

I want to be able to use the environment for definitions as well (which won't be numbered), so it should be possible to remove the number without affecting the alignment of the theorem head. Example:

```
      Definition   Statement of the definition. It should be aligned the same way as a 
      theorem. 

Here is some body text in the document. Note that the theorem numbers are not in the
margin. 

1.1   Theorem   Statement of the theorem. Here is some extra text so you can see how the
      theorem body text should be indented (aligned with theorem head).
```

Comment: @Sigur: I know how to interchange `thmnumber` and `thmname`, its the alignments that I don't know how to do.

Comment: it would be helpful to say what document class you intend to use.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: article

Comment: possible duplicate of [Numbering theorems in the left margin](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155823/numbering-theorems-in-the-left-margin)

Comment: Similar, but not a duplicate. I want the numbers aligned with the body text, not in the margin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a way to do it; this will also comply with lists such as `enumerate` in the statement, which solutions with `\hangindent` won't.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe} % just for the example
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtheoremstyle{fctaylor}% name
  {\topsep}%      Space above
  {\topsep}%      Space below
  {\normalfont}%         Body font
  {}%         Indent amount (empty = no indent, \parindent = para indent)
  {\bfseries}% Thm head font
  {}%        Punctuation after thm head
  {0pt}%     Space after thm head: " " = normal interword space;
  {\makethmhead{#1}{#2}{#3}}

\newlength\fctaylortheoremindent
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength\fctaylortheoremindent{3em}} % <- customize here
\newlength\fctaylorlabelsep
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength\fctaylorlabelsep{1em}} % <- customize here

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\makethmhead}[3]{%
  \gdef\thisthmhead{%
    \makebox[\fctaylortheoremindent][l]{\bfseries#2}%
    {\bfseries#1}%
    \@ifnotempty{#3}{ (#3)}%
    \hspace{\fctaylorlabelsep}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\newenvironment{fctayloritemize}
 {\list{}{%
    \leftmargin=\fctaylortheoremindent
    \labelwidth=\dimexpr\fctaylortheoremindent-\labelsep\relax
    \itemindent=0pt
  }}
 {\endlist}

\NewDocumentCommand{\newfctaylortheorem}{smomo}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {\newtheorem*{fctaylor@#2}{#4}}
   {\IfNoValueTF{#3}
     {\IfNoValueTF{#5}
       {\newtheorem{fctaylor@#2}{#4}}
       {\newtheorem{fctaylor@#2}{#4}[#5]}}
     {\newtheorem{fctaylor@#2}[fctaylor@#3]{#4}}}%
  \NewDocumentEnvironment{#2}{o}
   {\IfNoValueTF{##1}{\begin{fctaylor@#2}}{\begin{fctaylor@#2}[##1]}%
    \begin{fctayloritemize}\item[\thisthmhead\hfill]}
   {\end{fctayloritemize}\end{fctaylor@#2}}%
}

\theoremstyle{fctaylor}
\newfctaylortheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newfctaylortheorem*{defn}{Definition}

\begin{document}
\section{One}

\begin{defn}
\lipsum*[2]
\end{defn}

\begin{thm}\label{A}
\lipsum*[2]
\end{thm}

\begin{thm}[Somebody]\label{B}
Something that should show how the text is split across line boundaries
and is correctly indented. And some equivalent conditions:
\begin{enumerate}[label=\upshape(\alph*),ref=(\alph*)]
\item a condition
\item another
\item and another
\end{enumerate}
which show the point made.
\end{thm}

\ref{A} and \ref{B}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm glad you noticed the problem with enumerate; I need that to work.

Comment: I have two more questions about customizing this code (by the way, it is easy to use and works perfectly). (1) How can I make a theorem with no heading (so it would be just the number and the body text of the theorem)? [I tried just leaving the theorem name blank: `\newfctaylortheorem{claim}{}` but that didn't work.] (2) How can I make it so that theorems (and claims, see above) are numbered by subsection instead of by section? (I know this is not recommended, but I want to do it anyway)? [I tried `\renewcommand{\thethm}{\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{thm}}` but it didn't work.] Thanks again.

Comment: Note that, with the numbering, theorems, claims, etc. should be consecutively numbered. I tried to do this as usual with the `thm` counter but got an error.

Comment: @fctaylor25 There were a couple of typos, I fixed them

Answer (score 5):

Here's a possibility using [`thmtools`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/thmtools) as a front-end for [`amsthm:`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsthm:)

[image]

The code (adjust the settings according to your needs; in particular, change `\thmindent` to get the desired hanging indentation for the theorem-like structures):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength\thmindent
\setlength\thmindent{2.5em}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  spaceabove=6pt, 
  spacebelow=6pt,
  headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,
  notefont=\normalfont\bfseries, 
  notebraces={(}{)},
  bodyfont=\normalfont,
  postheadspace=0.5em,
  numberwithin=section,
  headformat={\makebox[\thmindent]{\NUMBER\hfill}\NAME\NOTE},
  postheadhook=\hangindent=\thmindent
]{nuswapindented}
\declaretheoremstyle[
  spaceabove=6pt, 
  spacebelow=6pt,
  headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,
  notefont=\normalfont\bfseries, 
  notebraces={(}{)},
  bodyfont=\normalfont,
  postheadspace=0.5em,
  numbered=no,
  headformat={\makebox[\thmindent]{\mbox{}\hfill}\NAME\NOTE},
  postheadhook=\hangindent=\thmindent
]{unnuswapindented}
\declaretheorem[style=nuswapindented,name=Theorem]{theo}
\declaretheorem[style=unnuswapindented,name=Definition]{defi}

\begin{document}

\section{Test section}

\lipsum[4]
\begin{defi}
\lipsum[4]
\end{defi}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{theo}
\lipsum[4]
\end{theo}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Will it work when `enumerate` is used inside `thm`?

Comment: I tried: after an `enumerate` inside `theo` the margin is lost (and the `enumerate` is misplaced).

Comment: @egreg Yes, I should've thought about it.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done with the `ntheorem` package and its `change` theoremstyle. The spacing between theorem name and theoremnumber can be adjusted patching the change theorem style: I introduce a new dimension, `thlabelsep` which defaults to `0.5em` and can changed in the preamble:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

 \usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[thmmarks, amsmath, thref]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newdimen\thlabelsep
\global\thlabelsep0.5em
\makeatletter
\renewtheoremstyle{change}%
{\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##2\hskip\thlabelsep##1\theorem@separator]}%
{\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##2\hskip\thlabelsep##1\ (##3)\theorem@separator]}
\makeatother
\theoremstyle{change}
\thlabelsep1.5em
\theoremheaderfont{\bfseries\upshape}
\theoremseparator{}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]

\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}
\begin{document}

\section{Two Conjectures}

\begin{defn}
  A Sophie Germain prime is a prime number $ p $ such that $ 2p + 1$ is also prime.
\end{defn}

\begin{thm}
There is an infinity of twin primes. Related: There is an infinity of Sophie Germain primes. 
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: please add more text so that the indentation of lines after the first can be observed.  also, it would be better to use more standard fonts; `heuristica` is one that not everyone is likely to have.

Comment: I'll do that in a moment. Would sticking to just fourier be OK?

Comment: more people are likely to have fourier than heuristica, but really, unless a particular font is requested in a question, it's best to stick with the least common denominator, usually `cm` or `lm`.

Comment: @Bernard: I prefer CM roman.

Comment: @fctaylor25: changed font and body of theorem so as to have a two-line statement.

Comment: @Bernard: A couple of things: (1) the theorem body text should be aligned with the theorem head, (2) I'm not sure how to get rid of the number for definitions (I'm used to `amsthm`). I'd appreciate it if you would include that in the answer. Seems solid otherwise, thanks for the response!

Comment: But theorem body text *is* aligned with theorem head. You can check on the .odf. I guess it's an optical effect on the screen. For definition, I'll update in a moment (not sure what  definition  formatting is in amsthm).

Comment: Maybe I'm using the term incorrectly. What I mean is the body text should be aligned with the word "Theorem" rather than the theorem number.

Comment: I see. That's more complicated, as the length of the numbering may vary. I've updated my answer to add an example of an unnumbered definition.

Comment: It's easy  to realize the alignment if you want the theorem number in the margin, and the word ‘Theorem’ to begin at the text left margin.