# "Extra \else" error when combining breqn, thm-restate, and cleveref

Tags: cleveref, incompatibility, thmtools, breqn, bugs

I have a document that uses `breqn`, `thm-restate` (`thmtools`), and `cleveref`. I can't get it to compile.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{thm-restate}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{restatable}{theorem}{foo}
  Test
\end{restatable}

\end{document}
```

The output of pdflatex contains many errors like this:

```
! Extra \else.
<argument> \else 

l.11 \end{restatable}

! Extra \else.
\cref@ifstreq ... \@firstoftwo \else \let \@tempc 
                                                  \@secondoftwo \fi \expanda...
l.11 \end{restatable}

! Extra \else.
\cref@ifstreq ...i \expandafter \endgroup \@tempc 
                                                  {#3}{#4}
```

I have tried multiple (I think all) orders to load the packages.

My feeling is that this can be fixed by changing the definition of `\cref@ifstreq` but this is beyond my current LaTeX skills.

Is there a workaround? Should I report a bug? (In which of the packages?)

I use TeX Live 2019, which has `breqn` 0.98g, `thm-restate`/`thmtools` 67, and `cleveref` 0.21.4. These are all the latest packages from CTAN except for `thmtools`, which I tried to update to 68 but that did not help either.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wow, that's a nice finding (if you can call it that). . .

The order doesn't matter, but all three packages play a role in this (though `cleveref` is innocent).

First, `breqn` redefines LaTeX's `\@ifstar` to use `\@temp(a|b|c)` instead of `\reserved@(a|b|c)` (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/447584/134574) about these), so when you define a macro `\def\test{\@ifstar{A}{B}}`, then use `\test\else`, `\@tempc` ends up becoming the same as `\else` (which is dangerous).

`thmtools`'s code does so that `\begin{restatable}{theorem}{foo}` eventually becomes `\expandafter\foo\ifprint\else*\fi`, then the `\expandafter` expands the `\ifprint` (the name is actually `\ifthmt@thisistheone`) which, in your case, is true, because you used `\begin{restatable}`, not `\begin{restatable*}`. After the `\expandafter` finishes you are left with `\foo\else*\fi` (yes, this is bad :-).

Now guess what is the first thing `\foo` does?
YES! `\@ifstar`, and now `\@tempc` is `\else`.

`cleveref` is just unfortunate enough to use `\@tempc` in `\cref@ifstreq` here:

```latex
    \ifx\@tempa\@tempb%
      \let\@tempc\@firstoftwo%
    \else%
      \let\@tempc\@secondoftwo%
    \fi%
```

which is fine, until `\@tempc` is the same as `\else`. The `\ifx` test is false, so you have:

```latex
    \iffalse
    \@tempc % \else
      \@firstoftwo%
    \else%
      \let\@tempc\@secondoftwo%
    \fi%
```

and you can see where this is going. . .

Here's a patch that fixes `thm-restate`. The patch changes the `\expandafter\foo\ifprint\else*\fi` thing to make sure that the entire `\if...\fi` block is completely expanded before `\foo` (thus `\@ifstar`) has the chance to look at it.

```latex
\usepackage{xpatch} % Needs to be loaded before breqn
\makeatletter % The patch needs to appear after thm-restate is loaded
\xpatchcmd\thmt@restatable % fixing thm-restatable
  {\csname #3\@xa\endcsname\ifthmt@thisistheone\else*\fi}
  {\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
     \expandafter\noexpand\csname #3\endcsname
       \ifthmt@thisistheone\else*\fi}\x
  }{}{\FailedToPatch}
\makeatother
```

Full document:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xpatch} % Needs to be loaded before breqn

\usepackage{thm-restate}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\makeatletter % The patch needs to appear after thm-restate is loaded
\xpatchcmd\thmt@restatable % fixing thm-restatable
  {\csname #3\@xa\endcsname\ifthmt@thisistheone\else*\fi}
  {\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
     \expandafter\noexpand\csname #3\endcsname
       \ifthmt@thisistheone\else*\fi}\x
  }{}{\FailedToPatch}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{restatable}{theorem}{foo}
  Test
\end{restatable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was quick! So could this have been avoided by either breqn or cleveref following the suggestion in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/447584/what-macros-should-be-used-as-scratch-space to add a unique prefix to their scratch macros?

Comment: @real-or-random Yes, that would have avoided this problem. Although I think the guilty party here is `thmtools`: if it had been more cautious with its expansion, the other packages using `\@tempc` wouldn't have been a problem. This same error can hapen with `thmtools` and other packages (other than `cleveref` and `breqn`), but then it would require another unfortunate combination (which I looked for but couldn't find right now).

Comment: Unfortunately `thmtools` is not maintained currently, not even the email address of the previous maintainer is active. I'll try to reach out to the maintainers of `breqn` or `cleveref` to see if they're willing to implement a workaround.

Comment: @real-or-random Oh, yes, I forgot to mention that. I'd say you go for `breqn`: the maintainer is more active than `cleveref`'s. Also `cleveref` is innocent in this issue. The problem really is `thmtools` being sloppy with its expansion and `breqn` using a generic, all purpose token to do something that needs to be done more carefully.

Comment: This has been fixed in `breqn` v0.98h, relased on 2020-02-16, see https://github.com/wspr/breqn/commit/686a9ff0f9a2ecb652a65c2fd1210430475f98e6.